# htaccess and names with "-"

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want do a redirect in htaccess to all thing after MYSITE/, example:

MYSITE/web-developer/ -> MYSITE/c.php?n=web-developer

I tested this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://MYSITE/c.php?n=$1 [L]
```

It works for names without - (or simbols), example: developer, but not with names containing - and it redirect me to web-developer/index.php

How can I resolve it?

Comment: `.*` does most certainly match on any symbols, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `-` in a name. Your rule works perfect.

But you might have a .htaccess in the `web-developer` directory with its own rewrite rules, which prevent the `RewriteRule` from triggering.

Comment: "web-developer" directory (like others with - ) not exists.